# Building against an older glibc

Tags: linux, compatibility, gcc, glibc

Is it possible to build glibc/gcc/binutils in the version combo of say 2.4/4.6/2.22 (or some later version of GCC used by the oldest/'stablest' linux distro's still around)?

I would like to create standalone cross-compilers for MinGW, and have them work on more than glibc 2.14 (my current Fedora), in this order:

1. build glibc-`<old version>` with the standard distro compiler
2. build new binutils/gcc using this old glibc version
3. build cross-compilers using the new combination of tools.

Comment: How about installing each of these distros into a VM of their own? After compiling your project in the VM you could test it there, too.

Comment: The "other" system is not one I want to use for this. It probably won't work with my new hardware either :(

Comment: Or use `cross` - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65835163/887092. Or your own docker container.